# How can I retrieves divs into a dynamic page in Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, netbeans, dynamic-pages

I've been trying to specifically retrieve a div that changes to pass the turn to the other player on a dynamic page. I'm working with Selenium because I think that's the best option I have, but I'm not sure if there's another way to access divs.

When I use .findElement(By.className("player")) (I've also tried with cssSelector but nothing happens), I encounter the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) on project BombPartyBot: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

I've also tried changing Properties -> Actions and Run, but nothing happens, and I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm somewhat new to coding, so I hope you can help me.

PD: I'm working in NetBeans on the last version.

Comment: Can you run a simple "hello world" sort of app to start with just to make sure you can run something? You can always add the Selenium code later. https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/kb/docs/java/quickstart/ looks like a straightforward "hello world" maven app you could start with.

Comment: I tried to retrieve a div on the same page ("roomName"), and when I do this, it runs perfectly and gives me the name of the room (I think because "roomName" was loaded on the page when I joined it).

Comment: https://www.qatouch.com/blog/dynamic-web-elements-in-selenium/ details various ways to get dynamic elements. Maybe you need to put in an explicit or fluent wait like the page talks about?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want us to do with this info. You haven't provided any code for us to evaluate or HTML/page link for us to look at.